# Rails inline text field to action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, inline

I am new to rails and a little bit stuck with a challenge: I have a model with a "status" column, which can be 0 or 1. In index view, I want to put a direct link to change status from 0 to 1, this I can do. What I would like to do is ask a reason (text filed) for the status change, and send that text as a parameter to the corresponding action.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: You could use [`Window.prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt) for showing input dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use form_tag for the same, radio buttons for 0 or 1 and a text field for the reason

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your question is "how to pass form data along with a link" ?

While you can't do this strictly in term of html implementation, there are several ways to make it look at if you do.

## Styling a button like a link

Probably the easiest way would be to use a form, then style your button as a link. The advantage of that is that it won't need any javascript.

You first set up a form :

```
<%= form_tag my_action_path do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :reason %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Do it', class: 'submit' %>
<% end
```

Then, you style your input accordingly :

```
.submit { border: 0 none; background: none; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; }
.submit:hover { text-decoration: none; }
```

[See it running](http://jsfiddle.net/v6YqK/).

This implementation will fire a POST request, this is probably what you should use since the action implies user writing something rather than reading it (you can still pass `method: :get` if you prefer a GET request).

## Add input data as query string

You can also hook click event on link and change url to include input's content. Provided the following html :

```
<%= text_field_tag :reason %>
<%= link_to 'do it', my_action_path %>
```

You could do this in javascript :

```
$('a').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); # prevent link to be followed

  # compute an url adding the input content
  var new_url = $(this).attr('url') + '&?reason=' + $('input').val();

  # redirect user to that url
  window.location.href = new_url;
});
```

I'm not very fond of this solution, because you may have url encoding / length problems, and adding inputs outside forms is not valid html. And if you add a form, well, you have to also handle it's submit event (since pressing the "return / enter" key in a text field will submit its form).

## Use a form and submit it when clicking link

You can also use a regular form, then trigger its submit when clicking the link :

```
<%= form_tag my_action_path do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :reason %>
  <%= link_to 'Do it', my_action_path %>
<% end %>
```

Here, the javascript would be something like that :

```
$('a').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); # do not follow link
  $('form').submit(); # submit form instead
});
```